# Showing that 0 is positive recurrent

Tags: stochastic-processes, conditional-expectation

**The Problem**

Consider the aging chain on $\{0, 1, 2, \dots\}$ in which for any $n \geq 0$ the individual gets 1 day older from $n$ to $n+1$ with probability $p_n$ but dies and returns to age 0 with probability $1 - p_n$. Find conditions on the $p_n$'s that guarantee that:

(a) 0 is recurrent

**My Work**

We'll consider first the finite state space $\mathcal{S} = \{0,1,2,\dots,N\}$. In this finite state space, we have irreducibility and aperiodicity, so $\rho_{x0} + \rho_{xN} > 0$ for all $ x \in C =  \cal S - \{0,N\}$. So $p(i, i+1) = p_i, p(i, 0) = 1 - p_i$. And for $h(0) = 0, h(N) = 1$, we have 
\begin{align*}
h_N(N - 1) &= p_{N-1} \\
h_N(N-1) &= p_{N-2}p_{N-1} \\
& \vdots \\
h_N(1) &= p_1p_2\cdots p_{N-1} = {\bf P}_1(T_N < T_1) \\
{\bf P}_0(T_0 < T_N) &= p_0(1 - h_N(1)) + (1 - p_0) \\
\xrightarrow{N \to \infty} {\bf P}_0(T_0 < \infty) &= 1 \iff \lim_{N \to \infty}h_N(1) = 0
\end{align*}
Thus in order for $ {\bf P}_x(T_0 < \infty) = 1 $, we require that $\prod_{i=1}^\infty p_i = 0$, in words: that the infinite product goes to 0.

(b) 0 is positive recurrent

**My Work**

In order for 0 to be positive recurrent, we need ${\bf E}_0T_0 < \infty$, where ${\bf E}_0T_0$ is the expected time of first return to 0. So let $\cal S = \{0,1,2, \dots, N\}$, let $C = S - A, A = \{0,N\}$, and set $g(a) = 0 \ \forall a \in A$. {\color{red}So the calculations are}
\begin{align*}
{\bf E}_0T_0 &= \sum_{k = 0}^\infty k {\bf P}(T_0 = k) \\
&= \sum_{k=0}^\infty k \prod_{i=0}^{k-1} p_i(1 - p_k)
\end{align*}

**My Question**

I am stuck with showing positive recurrence. I am also unsure how to *compute ${\bf E}_0T_0$ "directly"* as I have been advised for a problem of this sort.

And even if I were show show positive recurrence (which would imply the existence of a stationary distribution $\pi$, how would I find $\pi(0)$?

Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 1):

I think your idea for (b) may be wrong

Consider it this way, to get back to state 0, you just need one step, or to jump all the way back with probability $1-p_n$, but to take one more step in our expected return we need to take a step with probability $p_n$.

So for example when we reach at day 100, we just one more 1 more day to "die" (go to state 0). If $p_n=0$ we don't move anymore, we die, and so $$\mathbb{E}_0[T_0] = 1 + \sum_{n=0}^\infty p_n$$